# android: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memclr8"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have updated Android Studio to the version 2.2 and I get this error when I try to open the app on the device with Android 6 (API 23):

```
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memclr8"
```

I use NDK and my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are set to 24.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I get the same issue -- with NDK 12b.  I see another community moved back to NDK 11c to address this.  For the moment I'm moving back to a target of 23, but a real solution here would be good!

Comment: Your NDK target platform (`APP_PLATFORM`) should not be higher than minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

`compileSdkVersion` is a *minimum* API level. You can't build against android-24 and run on android-23. You need to target android-23 or lower.

Comment: I think minSdkVersion is minimum API level, targetSdkVersion is maximum API level on which the app was tested.

Comment: Whoops. Typo. I meant `compileSdkVersion` (I think, I'm really more familiar with the ndk-build naming for things, but from a quick grep through the gradle plugin I believe it is `compileSdkVersion` rather than `targetSdkVersion`). `minSdkVersion` is correct for Java, but C++ doesn't (can't) have the same min/compile/target/max, only min. I guess the gradle build uses compile for this instead of min.

I'll edit the answer. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: The problem is I cannot change complieSdkTarget to 23, because I have target set to 24 and I use support library version 24.2.1. But on the emulator everything works.